# notify-send does not work with root on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, python, root, notify-send

I have a small python script that I start it using a shell script stored in 
**"/etc/X11/Xsession.d"**

The code is very simple it show a notification message

```
import os
import time

while True:
      os.system('notify-send -i "/opt/say/logo.png" "Title" "Message"')
time.sleep(30)
```

The code simply shows a notification message every 30 seconds. It works on Ubuntu 12.04 with no problem, but it does not work on Ubuntu 14.04. The shell script in **"/etc/X11/Xsession.d"**  run as a root and as result my python code run with root privileges. I do not really want root privileges. All I want is to be able to see the notification.

Answer (score 2):

You should send the notify message as the normal main user of your system, (ususally ID 1000):

```
#!/bin/bash
MAINUSER=$(cat /etc/passwd|grep 1000|sed "s/:.*$//g")
su $MAINUSER -c $"notify-send -i \"/opt/say/logo.png\" \"Title\" \"Message\""
```

(not sure, how to call it like this in your python script, but I hope it helps)